# Do C++ compilers optimize return-by-value member variables

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I have a pretty good grasp on C++ return value optimizations when the variable being returned goes out of scope with the function, but what about returning member variables? Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class NamedObject {
 public:
  NamedObject(const char* name) : _name(name) {}
  std::string name() const {return _name;}

 private:
  std::string _name;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  NamedObject obj("name");
  std::cout << "name length before clear: " << obj.name().length() << std::endl;
  obj.name().clear();
  std::cout << "name length after clear: " << obj.name().length() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
name length before clear: 4
name length after clear: 4
```

Clearly, the `obj.name().clear()` acts on a temporary copy, but what about the calls to `obj.name.length()`? `std::string::length()` is `const` member function and therefore guaranteed not to modify the string's state. It seems reasonable, then, that compilers should be allowed to not copy the member variable and just use it directly for calls to const member functions. Do modern C++ compilers make this optimization? Is there any reason why it shouldn't or can't be made?

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm not asking if the standard return value optimization works here; I understood why it doesn't at the time I originally asked the question. RVO the way it's usually defined doesn't work here simply because the value being returned doesn't go out of scope with the function.

What I'm asking is: if the compiler at the time of the call can determine that call will have no side-effects, is it allowed to skip the copy? i.e., can it act as if

```
obj.name().length()
```

were

```
obj._name.length()
```

Comment: @ltjax Isn't RVO just a special case of copy elision?

Comment: @JoBates: RVO is elimination of an object and a copy but not every copy elision is RVO.

Comment: To clarify: RVO isn't applicable to `name()` and you don't copy the returned value any time so there is no opportunity for any other copy elision.

Comment: @CharlesBailey There is a possible copy to a temporary. In-fact, it must have happened in my example, otherwise `.clear()` would change the length. My question is whether or not compilers realize it's okay to skip that copy when only `const` functions are being called on the return value like `.length()`.

Comment: @Jo : He's not saying there are no copies, he's saying there are no copies _other than `return _name;`_ (and that said statement is _not_ eligible for RVO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

**Unless the compiler sees into the implementation of the copy constructor and the `length()` method at the time of compiling `main` through inlining or some compiler specific magic, it will not be able to optimize away that copy.**

Long answer:

The C++ standard typically never directly prescribes which optimizations should or should not be performed.  In fact, an optimization is, almost by definition, something that does not alter the behavior of a well formed program.

If the compiler is able to prove that a particular invocation of `obj.name` results in a copy whose existence is unprovable by the observer, it is free to elide the copy.  That could be your case as well with just a bit of inlining, so this copy elision is theoretically allowed here, *because* you don't print out or use its effects in any way.

Now, upon a closer look, Clause 12.8 of the standard does list four additional circumstances (related to exception handling, callee's return value such as the inside of `name` in your case, and binding a temporary to a reference).  I list them in this post for easy reference, but none of them matches your case where the temporary is received from a call and is used to invoke a `const` method.

Therefore, these explicit "exceptions" do not allow optimizing away the copy simply by inspection of `main` and noticing the `const` qualifier of `length()`.

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and/or destructor for the object have side eﬀects. In such
>   cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted
>   copy/move operation as simply two diﬀerent ways of referring to the
>   same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of
>   the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the
>   optimization.  This elision of copy/move operations, called copy
>   elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be
>   combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> — in a return statement in a
>   function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of
>   a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause
>   parameter) with the same cvunqualiﬁed type as the function return
>   type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the
>   automatic object directly into the function’s return value
>
> — in a
>   throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile
>   automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter)
>   whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost enclosing
>   try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from the operand
>   to the exception object (15.1) can be omitted by constructing the
>   automatic object directly into the exception object
>
> — when a temporary
>   class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be
>   copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualiﬁed type, the
>   copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary
>   object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
>
> — when the
>   exception-declaration of an exception handler (Clause 15) declares an
>   object of the same type (except for cv-qualiﬁcation) as the exception
>   object (15.1), the copy/move operation can be omitted by treating the
>   exception-declaration as an alias for the exception object if the
>   meaning of the program will be unchanged except for the execution of
>   constructors and destructors for the object declared by the
>   exception-declaration.

Comment: For the short answer, the compiler would also need to see the implementation of the copy-constructor to verify it does not have side effects, as it does not meet the criteria for an optimization that is exempted from side effects.

Comment: @Jirka Thank you. I think you should add twansbury's suggestion to the short answer, but otherwise, this is exactly what I was looking for: an explanation as to why its technically possible but highly unlikely.

FYI, I checked the assembly output of both clang and and gcc and someone else's answer already checked msvc. None of them make the theoretical optimization. I imagine you'd need an extremely smart compiler to know copy elision would have no visible effect, or another exception added to the standard.

Comment: Thanks both for great comments, incorporated.  I don't think the compiler would have to be extremely smart.  Both gcc and msvc would probably cope if only the members were defined in the header file and optimizations turned on.

Answer (score 7):

The `name()` function returns by value, which means that all operations are performed on temporaries.

> It seems reasonable, then, that compilers should be allowed to not copy the member variable and just use it directly for calls to const member functions.

This assumption is incorrect on many grounds. When a function is declared as `const` **you** are telling the compiler that you will not modify the state of the object so that the compiler can help you verify that. The return type is part of the checks that the compiler can do for you. If you, for example, change the return type to be:

```
std::string& name() const { return _name; }
```

The compiler will complain: you promised that `name()` would not modify the state, but you are providing a reference through which *others* can do it. Additionally, the semantics of that function is that it provides a *copy* that the caller can modify. If the copy was elided (it is impossible to elide it, but for the sake of argument), then calling code could modify what seems like a local copy and actually modify the state of your object.

In general, when providing accessors that are const, you should return *references* to the members rather than *copies*.

> I have a pretty good grasp on C++ return value optimizations for temporaries, [...] Do modern C++ compilers make this optimization? Is there any reason why it shouldn't or can't be made?

I have the feeling that you don't really have a good grasp on what the return value optimizations are, or else you would not make the second question. Lets work this on an example. When user code has:

```
std::string foo() {
   std::string result;
   result = "Hi";
   return result;
}
std::string x = foo();
```

In the code above there are potentially three strings: `result` inside `foo`, the return value (lets call it `__ret`) and `x`, and two possible optimizations that can be applied: *NRVO* and generic *copy-elision*. *NRVO* is an optimization performed by the compiler when processing the function `foo`, and it consists in mergint `result` and `__ret` by placing them over the same location and creating a single object. The second part of the optimization must be done in the caller side, and again it merges the locations of the two objects `x` and `__ret`.

As of the actual implementation, I will start with the second one. The caller (in most calling conventions) is responsible for the allocation of the memory for the returned object. Without optimizations (and in a kind of pseudocode) this is what goes on on the caller:

```
[uninitialized] std::string __ret;
foo( [hidden arg] &__ret );          // Initializes __ret
std::string x = __ret;
```

Now, because the compiler knows that the temporary `__ret` will only life to initialize `x` it transforms the code into:

```
[uninitialized] std::string x;
foo( [hidden arg] &x );             // Initializes x
```

And the copy of the caller is elided. The copy inside `foo` is elided in a similar way. The transformed (to comply with the calling convention) function is:

```
void foo( [hidden uninitialized] std::string* __ret ) {
   std::string result;
   result = "Hi";
   new (__ret) std::string( result );   // placement new: construct in place
   return;
}
```

Now the optimization in this case is exactly the same. Since `result` lives only to be able to initialize the returned object, it can reuse the same space, rather than creating a new object:

```
void foo( [hidden uninitialized] std::string* __ret ) {
   new (__ret) std::string();
   (*__ret) = "Hi";
   return;
}
```

Now going back to your original problem, because the member variable exists before the member function is called, this optimization cannot be applied. The compiler cannot place the return value on the same location that the member attribute is, since that variable is already alive in a known location that is not the address of `__ret` (provided by the caller).

I wrote about [NRVO](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) and [copy elision](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html) in the past. You might be interested in reading those articles.

Comment: When I said "return value optimizations for temporaries", I meant variables whose scope ends with he function call. I probably misused the word "temporary" there. But, yes, I already understood everything in your example. That's why I was asking the question: I'm aware returning a value with scope beyond the function call (in this case, it has the same lifetime as the class instance) is a fundamentally different problem.

Comment: @JoBates: inlining is a whole different optimization problem, completely unrelated to return value optimization. Also, if you did understand how the optimization works, then you already understood that the optimization cannot be applied to members. One point that you might have missed from the answer is that (unless it inlines the code and analyzes everything, which is again unrelated to RVO), the compiler *inside* the function cannot know whether the caller will modify the variable to return a reference otherwise. And the caller *must* provide the space in the stack.

Comment: @dribeas I know that "the return value optimization" as it's usually described doesn't apply to member variables. I'm not asking if that specific optimization works here, I'm asking if the optimization I'm describing can be made. It is, in-fact, an optimization which revolves around whether or not a return value needs to be copied to a temporary location or if some other pre-existing location can be re-used. The fact that it could be inlined is just the implementation of my optimization I came up with to get around the fact that one function implementation couldn't cover every case.

Comment: @dribeas Sorry, the notion of someone thinking I don't understand the problem because I happened to mention an arguably similar problem first really bugs me and I feel the immense need to clarify. You keep saying I don't understand RVO because RVO doesn't work here but I never said that it did or that it might. I just mentioned RVO because I think it's similar is all. Like I said, both RVO and my theoretical optimization revolving around skipping the copy of a return value.

Comment: @JoBates: If the compiler is able to inline then it can potentially optimize everything that you could do, but the fact is that I would not count on that (even if the function is inlined). The fact that `length()` is marked as `const` does not mean that the copy can be avoided, it could modify some internal *mutable* state and cause your program not to behave *as-if* the copy had been done. The chances of optimizing that are little and I don't expect compiler writers to spend any time trying to provide an optimization that is otherwise useless (if you want an accessor, return a `const&`)

Comment: @Jo *I have a pretty good grasp on C++ return value optimizations when the variable being returned goes out of scope with the function, but what about returning member variables?* -- I guess you can interpret that in other ways, but the first that comes to mind is: *Can RVO be applied when returning member variables?* And thus my answer: No, it makes no sense.

Comment: @dribeas It only takes one vaguely written sentence... thanks for your patience and thorough explanations. I was definitely wrong about `const` guaranteeing anything; thanks for pointing that out. The question is answered!

Answer (score 1):

> is const member function and therefore guaranteed not to modify the string's state

That's not true. `std::string` may have a `mutable` data member, and any function may cast the `const` off `this` or any member of it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know the `mutable` keyword existed!

Comment: @JoBates: I used it once. It felt kind of dirty.

Comment: One could argue that mutable members are not part of an object's state, therefore modifying them is not modifying the object's state.

Comment: Well, in C and C++, we can go ahead and try modifying any data with an address yet I'm under the impression compilers make assumptions about the const-ness of `const` variables. So, while there's no guarantee `length()` won't modify `_name`, I wouldn't put it past a compiler to assume it.

Comment: mutable ranks up there with const_cast on the dirty chart :)

Comment: @JoBates: but writing to an arbitrary memory address is UB already, so that's covered. `const_cast` has defined semantics that severely limit the protection offered by `const`.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I just checked the (open source) codebase where I used it, and the current maintainers have used it several more times. I'm starting to guilty as well now :p

Comment: I don't understand the `mutable` hate. There's a difference between state and _observable_ state -- `mutable` is fine for _unobservable_ state.

Comment: It can also be a crutch to get at "hidden" data members like a friend.  Yes, like any tool, it can be used for good, but for so much evil as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The return value optimizations are about eliminating the implicit copy in the return statement by eliminating the temporary or object with scope local to the function and using the object being eliminated as an alias for the return object.

Obviously, this only applies if the function is constructing the object being used in the return statement. If the object being returned already exists, there is no extra object being created so the object being returned must be copied to the return object. There is no other object construction in the function that can be eliminated.

Not withstanding all of the above, the compiler can make any optimizations it sees fit so long as no difference in behaviour can be observed by a conforming program so anything (non-observable) is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn what optimizations your compiler makes is to look at the assembly it generates and see exactly what the compiler actually does. It's very hard to predict what kind of optimizations a given compiler may or may not make under every situation, and most people are usually either too pessimistic or way too optimistic.

On the other hand, by just examining the compiler's output, you can see exactly what it does without needing any guesswork.

In Visual Studio, you can get a helpful output of assembly interleaved with the source code through setting project properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output -> "Assembly with source code", or [just supplying /Fas to the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You can tell GCC to output assembly with [-S](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html), but that won't correlate the lines of assembly with lines of source; for that [you have to use objdump](http://24alpha.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/how-to-get-gcc-to-interleave-assembly-output-with-original-source-code/) or maybe [the -fverbose-asm  commandline option](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-03/msg00458.html) if it happens to work in your version.

For example, one of the blocks from your code (compiled under full release in MSVC) is :

```
; 23   :    obj.name().clear();

    lea ecx, DWORD PTR _obj$[esp+92]
    push    ecx
    lea esi, DWORD PTR $T23719[esp+96]
    call    ?name@NamedObject@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ ; NamedObject::name
    mov DWORD PTR [eax+16], ebx
    cmp DWORD PTR [eax+20], edi
    jb  SHORT $LN70@main
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax]
$LN70@main:
    mov BYTE PTR [eax], bl
    mov ebx, DWORD PTR __imp_??3@YAXPAX@Z
    cmp DWORD PTR $T23719[esp+112], edi
    jb  SHORT $LN84@main
    mov edx, DWORD PTR $T23719[esp+92]
    push    edx
    call    ebx
    add esp, 4
$LN84@main:

; 24   :    std::cout << "name length after clear: " << obj.name().length() << std::endl;

    lea eax, DWORD PTR _obj$[esp+92]
    push    eax
    lea esi, DWORD PTR $T23720[esp+96]
    call    ?name@NamedObject@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ ; NamedObject::name
    mov BYTE PTR __$EHRec$[esp+100], 2
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@AAV21@@Z
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax+16]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    push    ecx
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_0BK@PFKLDML@name?5length?5after?5clear?3?5?$AA@
    push    edx
    call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
    add esp, 8
    mov ecx, eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@I@Z
    mov ecx, eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z
    cmp DWORD PTR $T23720[esp+112], edi
    jb  SHORT $LN108@main
    mov eax, DWORD PTR $T23720[esp+92]
    push    eax
    call    ebx
    add esp, 4
```

(You can undecorate MSVC symbol names with [undname.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx)) As you can see, in this case it calls the `NamedObject::name()` function both before .clear() and again before .length().